# Another Bracket Script issue

Tags: autohotkey, autocomplete, brackets, braces

I use AutoHotKey to autocomplete all kind of brackets in the following way:

- typing  (    gives (    -> opening brace bracket only
- typing  ((   gives ()   -> open & close brace with input cursor between the braces.

The same thing happen for square brackets []  and curly brackets {}.

My code for braces (for example) is as follow:

```
{ ; Automatic BRACES
  :*?:((::
    SendInput, {Raw}()
    Send {SPACE} 
    SendInput, {Left 2}
  return
}
```

After pressing the double opening brace, I enter my text between the braces, then simply press END and continue typing.  The space after the closing brace is already added.

MY PROBLEM:

I would like quotes "" to behave the same way but obviously AHK treat quotes differently and I cannot figure how.   With the Code :

```
{ ; Automatic Quotes
  :*?:""::
    Send {U+0022}
    Send {U+0022}
    Send {SPACE} 
    SendInput, {Left 2} 
    return
}
```

pressing "  -> nothing happen.

pressing "" -> make a double quote with the cursor in-between (as expected)

Changing the code to :

```
{ ; Automatic Quotes
  :*?:"::
    Send {U+0022}
    Send {U+0022}
    Send {SPACE} 
    SendInput, {Left 2} 
   return
 }
```

will add "" with cursor in-between after one single press of the "  key.

QUESTION:

Does anyone have an idea how I can make QUOTES behave the same way as my other brackets?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a whole lot easier to just type () etc., as you're right there, then backspace one?

Comment: Or use an editor that already implements entering paired delimiters, e.g., [], {} and "", such as free Notepad++, https://notepad-plus-plus.org/  (or perhaps Kate). The right editor makes writing code *much* easier, including language parsing, finding unpaired delimiters and formatting (pretty printing).

Comment: The advantage with AHK is that it works everywhere, not just in one application at a time.

I want to implement this shortcut for the purpose of speed.  It is much faster to type twice the same key that 3 different ones.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the AutoHotKey
[Hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotstrings.htm)
with a script like this:

```
:*:""::
Send,""
Send,{Left}
return
```

The hoststring here is `""`.
The `*` option means that AHK doesn't wait
for an ending character after the `""`.

Comment: I am sorry,  but this is not working:

Comment: The  `Send,""` does not generate double quote.  it just do nothing.
This is the reason why I used `Send {U+0022} Send {U+0022}`.
Does it depend of your Keyboard Layout ?  Mine is German-Germany

Comment: I have the feeling you're using AutoHotKey V2 while I'm using V1. If that's the case, you'll need to translate my commands to V2.

Comment: Sorry to contradict you, Harry but I use AHK v. 1.1.33.02

Your code does not work for me.
Is that Keyboard Layout dependent ?

Comment: Very strange. I updated my AHK to version 1.1.37.01 and it's still working for me. Try it with an `.ahk` file that contains just my text and no more. If it still doesn't work, try to add `Sleep,10` between the two `Send` commands.